# How to make Dynamic checkbox with Api data?

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, checkboxlist

**How to make using Listview.builder() and handle it click in flutter**

Comment: What data? What checkbox? What exactly *can* you do, and at which part of it are you stuck?

Comment: i could not handle checkbox click in listview builder.

Comment: To break it down: Do you have a list of data? Do you have a listview builder that builds one element per data item? Do you have a checkbox in that list? Can you bind a click handler? Do you know how to do state management and if so which solution do you prefer? We need to know *where* on this list of steps you are. You can describe it, or you can post your current code and the error messages.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly how Stack Overflow works. I clicked the downvote button because your question "does not show any research effort" and "is unclear". It is up to you whether you will use your frustration about someone downvoting (that we certainly all have) to just be angry and do nothing or if you edit your question with the things I asked about. Because other people might not downvote you, but without the actual information in the question, there will probably not be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way to achieve your goal, try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SimpleTest> createState() => _SimpleTestState();
}

class _SimpleTestState extends State<SimpleTest> {
  List<int> selectedItem = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 8,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text("Check Box$index"),
                              value: selectedItem.contains(index) ? true : false,
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                if (selectedItem.contains(index)) {
                                  selectedItem.remove(index);
                                } else {
                                  selectedItem.add(index);
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```